# Algorithms & Technology For Finding Language Server Problems in XML

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

There is an issue that seems trivial but fascinating to me and I want to learn. I am developing software on Apache Maven and it contains a configuration file named *pom.xml.* Whenever I add an erroneous entry as such: < john>3.2.0 </ jack > .
It gives two errors. These are as such:

> Non-parseable POM C:\Users\username\path\to\application\pom.xml: end
> tag name </ jack > must match start tag name < john> from line 32

and

> The element type "john" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
> "".    pom.xml /anket  line 32 Language Servers

The point that I want to learn is which tool (eclipse, maven, whatsoever ) detect this anomaly and which technology or algorithm it uses to detect it? It is XML data, so I assume that neither JRE nor JDK can find out this anomaly. Assume that I want to write software that detects such anomalies, how can I do this?

Comment: Currently, [Eclipse m2e](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/) uses [LemMinX-Maven](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx-maven) which extends [LemMinX](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx) that provides XML support, including showing of  errors of invalid XML. All of these are implemented in Java. LemMinX-Maven and LemMinX are language servers. In the past, m2e used [Eclipse WTP](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/xml/overview.html) instead of LemMinX-Maven.